# t-sql Pivot on aggregated column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have had a look through the pivot related queries but can't seem to find one that matched what I would like to do. I have a table as follows:-

```
type  |  iscurrent
-----------------
A     |  1
A     |  1
A     |  0
B     |  1
B     |  1
B     |  1
C....
```

I want to pivot this data so it looks as follows, the ***iscurrent*** field will only ever have 0's and 1's in it.

```
TYPE  |  1  |  0
-----------------
A     |  2  |  1
B     |  3  |  0
C     | ...
```

the code I had so far was

```
SELECT loadid, '1', '0'
FROM (
SELECT iscurrent, loadid
FROM #table) up
PIVOT (sum(iscurrent) FOR iscurrent IN ([1], [0])) AS pvt
ORDER BY loadid
GO
```

I get a bit operand error when i try and run the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT loadid, [1], [0]
```

and

```
PIVOT (count(isCurrent) FOR iscurrent IN ([1], [0])) AS pvt
```

ie:

```
SELECT loadid, [1],[0]
FROM (  SELECT iscurrent, loadid FROM #table) up
PIVOT (count(iscurrent) FOR iscurrent IN ([1], [0])) AS pvt
ORDER BY loadid
```